# How to make CMake to set Visual Studio linker's option Generate Debug Info as yes?

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake to generate Visual Studio project. In my release edition, I also want to set Visual Studio project's one property as Yes, which is properties ==> Configuration Properties ==> Linker ==> Debugging ==> Generate Debug Info.

Is it possible?

Comment: How about using the RelWithDebugInfo configuration? This one will have debug info enabled and CMake supports that.

Comment: Upvoted both the question and the answer below. RelWithDebugInfo configuration is less optimized than Release, and I really wanted to produce pdb for "proper" one. Note that you also need to specify /Zi flag: `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi")`

Comment: ``CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`` isn't supported for the "VS" generator. It only has Debug and Release modes, and the Release as debug turned off by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add custom linker options using the [`LINK_FLAGS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS.html) target property:

```
add_executable(foo ${FOO_SOURCES})
if(MSVC)
    set_property(TARGET foo APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS /DEBUG)
endif()
```

If you are already on CMake version 3.13 or higher, you should use the [`LINK_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/prop_tgt/LINK_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:LINK_OPTIONS) property instead (thanks to [@bsa for pointing this out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858792/how-to-make-cmake-to-set-visual-studio-linkers-option-generate-debug-info-as-ye/24861589?noredirect=1#comment99391299_24861589)). CMake even provides a [handy command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) for setting this:

```
add_executable(foo ${FOO_SOURCES})
if(MSVC)
    target_link_options(foo PUBLIC /DEBUG)
endif()
```

This sets the `/DEBUG` flag for all configurations on Visual Studio builds. It is also possible to add the flag [only for a specific configuration](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS_CONFIG.html).

Note that this really only sets the linker flag and nothing else. If you want a fully functional debug build, you will have to set other flags as well. As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858792/how-to-make-cmake-to-set-visual-studio-linkers-option-generate-debug-info-as-ye#comment38606662_24858792), you should avoid fiddling with those flags manually and prefer using one of the provided configurations instead, as it can be quite difficult to get right.

Comment: Also note that `LINK_OPTIONS` is preferred to `LINK_FLAGS` since CMake version 3.13 https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:LINK_OPTIONS

Comment: @bsa Good catch, I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks!